# Full width accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I did a very simple horizontal full width accordion but I'm experiencing a bug - The last part of it goes down during the collapsing.

Here my code : https://jsfiddle.net/trzxs3u1/

It might come from the closing and opening which are animated at the same time but I can't find what I'm doing wrong :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var qtySect = 3 - 1;
    var unselectedWidth = 40 / qtySect +"%";
    var selectedWidth = 60+"%";
    $("div ul li:first-child").addClass('selected');
    $("div ul li").not(':first-child').addClass('unselected');
    $(".unselected").css("width", unselectedWidth);
    $(".selected").css("width",selectedWidth);
    $("div ul li").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("unselected")){
             $(this).animate( { width: selectedWidth }, { queue: false, duration: 300, easing: "linear" } )
             $(".selected").animate( { width: unselectedWidth }, { queue: false, duration: 300, easing: "linear" } );
            $(".selected").addClass("unselected").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected").removeClass("unselected");
        }
    });
});
```

Do you have any idea why is doing that ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue? I don't understand "The last part of it goes down during the collapsing" and it seems working in the fidd

Comment: @CarlK Go in the jsfiddle and directly click on the "pane #3", you'll see that  this part will go under the two others during the animation.

Comment: @CarlK I'm testing in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just with you are using whole 100% of body canvas
just

var unselectedWidth = 40 / qtySect +"%"; reduce to var unselectedWidth = 39 / qtySect +"%";

else you can reduce the 60% portion to 59% coz in html elements brought some padding with it  and other way is to set the all elements of html with padding 0 (it's not the good one) i would prefer first one...

```js
$(function () {
  //Remove 1 element(selected), and find the width of the rest(unselected)
    var qtySect = 3 - 1;
    var unselectedWidth = 39 / qtySect +"%"; /// made a change 
    var selectedWidth = 60+"%";

        //set initial widths
    $("div ul li:first-child").addClass('selected');
    $("div ul li").not(':first-child').addClass('unselected');
    $(".unselected").css("width", unselectedWidth);
    $(".selected").css("width",selectedWidth);
        //click animate
    $("div ul li").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("unselected")){
             $(this).animate( { width: selectedWidth }, { queue: false, duration: 300, easing: "linear" } )
             $(".selected").animate( { width: unselectedWidth }, { queue: false, duration: 300, easing: "linear" } );
            $(".selected").addClass("unselected").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected").removeClass("unselected");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.wrapper ul {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper li {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.pane1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.pane2 {
    background-color: green;
}

.pane3 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.pane4 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
     <ul>
         <li class="pane1">Pane #1</li>
         <li class="pane2">Pane #2</li>
         <li class="pane3">Pane #3</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```